# InnerHTML doesn't work with if condition in regExp

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to add some confirmation to my form using RegExp
The thing is that i use some condition in that way i can show to the user that the input is correct or not
So i've created a  below my input and using nextElementSibling and after that i'm using a innerHtml to add some Text and show it to the user
here's the project on my GitHub https://github.com/Chardema/openclassroomp3.github.io
But that doesn't work
The  is correct and JS can have access to it
here's my code

```
const validFirst = function (inputFirst) {
  let msg;
  let valid = false;
  // au moins 2 caractère
  if (inputFirst.value.length < 2) {
    msg = "Le prénom est trop court";
  } else {
    msg = "le prenom est correct !!!";
    valid = true;
  }
  //Affichage
  //Récupération de la balise Small
  let small = inputFirst.nextElementSibling;

  //on test l'expression régulière
  if (valid) {
    small.innerHtml = "OK ‍";
    small.classList.remove("text-danger");
    small.classList.add("text-success");
  } else {
    small.innerHtml = "c pas bon cthistoire ";
    small.classList.remove("text-success");
    small.classList.add("text-danger");
  }
};
```

and the HTML

```
     <div
        class="formData">
        <label for= "first">Prénom</label>
        <input
          class="text-control"
          type="text"
          id="first"
          name="first"
          minlength="2"
        />
        <small></small>


         </div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few console messages show your code is fine up to the point where the text is sent to the page. This allows the error to be found - `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML`;

In the working snippet, I've called the function from the input's `onchange` event (so click outside the input after entering something). If you call by some other method, be sure to check the function receives the element and that each stage is performing the tasks expected of it. I also used 'test' as inner content of the `small` element to ensure all was as expected.

```js
const validFirst = function (inputFirst) {
  console.log(inputFirst.value.length);
  let msg;
  let valid = false;
  // au moins 2 caractère
  if (inputFirst.value.length < 2) {
    msg = "Le prénom est trop court";
  } else {
    msg = "le prenom est correct !!!";
    valid = true;
  }
  console.log(valid, msg);
  //Affichage
  //Récupération de la balise Small
  let small = inputFirst.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(small.innerText);
  //on test l'expression régulière
  if (valid) {
    small.innerHTML = "OK ‍";
    //small.classList.remove("text-danger");
    //small.classList.add("text-success");
  } else {
    small.innerHTML = "c pas bon cthistoire ";
    small.classList.remove("text-success");
    small.classList.add("text-danger");
  }
};
```

```html
     <div
        class="formData">
        <label for= "first">Prénom</label>
        <input
          class="text-control"
          type="text"
          id="first"
          name="first"
          minlength="2"
          onchange="validFirst(this)" 
        />
        <small>test</small>


         </div>
```

Comment: Well... that's embarassing hum... THANK YOU SO MUCH at least  i hope i'm not going to reproduce that...

Comment: easily done and infuriating when not spotted. Console messages are the key to finding the point of failure and making it easier to spot typos.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `.innerHtml` by `.innerHTML`